# If $\sum\limits_{n=2}^∞\frac1{f(n)}=ζ(C)-1$, is it ok to write $\lim\limits_{n→∞}f(n)=n^C$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, riemann-zeta

Consider a function $f(n)$ such that $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{f(n)} = \zeta (C)-1 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^C}.$$
Is it ok to write $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)=n^C?$$

Comment: Unfortunately, in general no.

Comment: i can see why, but in this case, $f(n)-f(n-1) > 0$ for all n from $0 \to \infty$, does that makes a difference ?

Comment: The limit  $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$ cannot depend on $n$. You could ask whether $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^C} = 1$.